# Selecting all rows in a master table and summing columns in multiple detail tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a master table (Project List) along with several sub tables that are joined on one common field (RecNum). I need to get totals for all of the sub tables, by column and am not sure how to do it. This is a sample of the table design. There are more columns in each table (I need to pull * from "Project List") but I'm showing a sampling of the column names and values to get an idea of what to do.

```
Project List
| RecNum | Project Description |
|      6 | Sample description  |
|      7 | Another sample      |

WeekA
| RecNum | UserName | Day1Reg | Day1OT | Day2Reg | Day2OT | Day3Reg | Day3OT |
|      6 | JustMe   |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |       5 |      6 |
|      6 | NotMe    |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |       5 |      6 |
|      7 | JustMe   |         |        |         |        |         |        |
|      7 | NotMe    |         |        |         |        |         |        |

WeekB
| RecNum | UserName | Day1Reg | Day1OT | Day2Reg | Day2OT | Day3Reg | Day3OT |
|      6 | JustMe   |       7 |      8 |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |
|      6 | NotMe    |       7 |      8 |       1 |      2 |       3 |      4 |
|      7 | JustMe   |         |        |         |        |         |        |
|      7 | NotMe    |         |        |         |        |         |        |
```

So the first query should return the complete totals for both users, like this:

```
| RecNum | Project Description | sumReg | sumOT |
|      6 | Sample description  |     40 |    52 |
|      7 | Another sample      |      0 |     0 |
```

The second query should return the totals for just a specified user, (WHERE UserName = 'JustMe') like this:

```
| RecNum | Project Description | sumReg | sumOT |
|      6 | Sample description  |     20 |    26 |
|      7 | Another sample      |      0 |     0 |
```

Comment: Would you know how to do this if you had a single "Weeks" table?

Comment: It would also be far far better if `day` were a column in the `Weekx` tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple parallel tables with the same structure is usually a sign of poor database design.  The data should really be all in one table, with additional columns specifying the week.

You can, however, use `union all` to bring the data together.  The following is an example of a query:

```
select pl.recNum, pl.ProjectDescription,
       sum(Day1Reg + Day2Reg + Day3Reg) as reg,
       sum(Day1OT + Day2OT + Day3OT) as ot
from ProjectList pl join
     (select * from weekA union all
      select * from weekB
     ) w
     on pl.recNum = w.recNum
group by l.recNum, pl.ProjectDescription,;
```

In practice, you should use `select *` with `union all`.  You should list the columns out explicitly. You can add appropraite `where` clauses or conditional aggregation to get the results you want in any particular case.

Comment: Actually, this works for the most part. It gives the correct results, but because "Group By" is used, it makes the results not editable. If I remove the "Group By" then I only get a single row as a result. Any other possibilities?

Comment: @user2021539 . . . If you have a question about updates, then you should ask that as another question.  This question seems pretty clearly to be about `select`.

Comment: Actually, no. I want to select then have the ability to modify the selected data in a View.